# Non-one indexed array from associate

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I would like to have an associate that points to an array (or parts thereof) and is not one indexed.
The following program illustrates the problem:

```
program test_associate
    implicit none(type, external)
    integer, parameter :: N = 10
    integer :: i, A(0 : N - 1)

    A = [(i, i = lbound(A, 1), ubound(A, 1))]
    write(*, *) A(0), A(9)

    associate(B => A(0 : N - 1))
        write(*, *) B(9)    ! This writes 8 but should write 9
    end associate
end program
```

I tried

```
    associate(B(0 : N - 1) => A(0 : N - 1))
        write(*, *) B(9)
    end associate
```

but this is invalid syntax. (at least in my compiler which is gfortran 9.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax

```
associate (B(0:N-1) => ...)
end associate
```

is not valid in Fortran: the left-hand side of the association item must be a *name*. With just a name (which here would be `B`) it isn't possible to specify properties such as bounds.

The bounds of the associating entity array (again, here `B`), are given by the results of using `LBOUND` on the right-hand side (the *selector*) (Fortran 2018, 11.1.3.3 p.1):

> The lower bound of each dimension is the result of the intrinsic function `LBOUND` (16.9.109) applied to the corresponding dimension of *selector*

The referenced description of `LBOUND` explains how the bound is calculated in this case.

Because `A(0:N-1)` is not a whole array, `LBOUND` returns `1`, and so the lower bound of `B` in this case is itself `1`.

It is possible to have the lower bound of `B` be something other than `1`: have the selector being a whole array. In

```
associate(B => A)
end associate
```

`B` will have lower bound that of `A`.

In conclusion: it's possible for an associate entity to have lower bound other than `1`, but only when the thing it's associated with is a whole array. In particular, in associating with part of an array (and that can include *all* of the array, such as `B => A(:)`, `A(:)` not being a whole array) the associating entity always has lower bounds `1`.

As Vladimir F says in another answer, a pointer can have bounds controlled as part of pointer assignment.

Comment: From your answer I see that my minimal example is too minimal. In my actual code I have a rank higher than 1 and use the `associate` to point to one row. Similar to this statement
`associate(row => A(0 : N, i, j))` 
In such cases my rhs expressions is never a whole array, so I will always end up with a one-indexed associating entity array? (Unless of course I use pointers as in Vladimir's answer.)

Comment: Indeed: there's no way to select just along one dimension of many and still have a whole array. You would be stuck in this case with 1-indexing. Associating with a whole array for reasons other than "giving a new convenient name for some horrible reference" is quite rare so it's generally going to be the case that you will have 1-indexing.

Comment: Rather than using pointers instead of an associate construct you may find `call work_on_row(row=A(0:N,i,j),lbound=0)` more helpful. If what would be in the associate construct is complicated by having to deal with non-default bounds then there's an argument that putting that work in a procedure is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that is possible. `A(0 : N - 1)` is a subarray, it is an expression, no longer the original array. The lower bound of `A(0 : N - 1)` is 1, not 0.

You can try

```
dimension A(0:9)
print *,lbound(A(0:8))
end
```

It will print `1`.

Be aware, that your associate may case the array section to be copied and stored in a temporary array.

If you associate to `=> B`, `A` will correctly write `9`.

You can use pointers to point to such sections

```
program test_associate
    implicit none(type, external)
    integer, parameter :: N = 10
    integer, target :: A(0 : N - 1)
    integer, pointer :: B(:)
    integer :: i

    A = [(i, i = lbound(A, 1), ubound(A, 1))]
    write(*, *) A(0), A(9)
    
    B(0:N-1) => A(0:N-1)
    write(*, *) B(9)    ! This writes 9

end program
```

Comment: Does `i` have to be a target? PS: I am sorry to not accept your answer officially, if I could accept both I would happily do so.

Comment: @mcocdawc It does. You can accept any answer you want. I did not address the reason for the compiler error (the syntax is just invalid), just the bounds issue and how to do it.

Comment: But `i` is never pointed to by any pointer and it compiles with at least gfortran and all warnings enabled, if `i` is not a target.

Comment: @mcocdawc Sure, I did not check the symbol name you were asking about. The array pointed to must be target. Nothing else. Probably my fast change of your code confused you.